# Logback and logging specific package in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I'm using Spring Boot v2.3.9.RELEASE with the Logback framework.

I want Spring/Logback to log debug messages, but it refuses to do so. The application.yml has multiple ways to plead with it to log DEBUG messages. I saw multiple ways of doing a specific package. I my attempts for application.yml below:

```
spring:
  logging:
    level:
        com.mycompany.mypackage: DEBUG
logging:
  level:
    com.mycompany.mypackage: DEBUG
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but the YAML indentation above is 2 spaces per level.

Invoked using:

```
    ...
    protected static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ToolClient.class);
    ...
    log.debug("My debugging statement");
```

Had I chosen log.info("..."), it would have worked.

Which incantation of application.yml do I need to do to get Logback to work?

Comment: Do you have additional Logback configurations, where you e.g. restrict the log level for specific appenders?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure logging appenders. Setting log levels is not enough.
Please check out this article [spring-boot-logging](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging)